# Is there a way to SSH (exec) into a Kubernetes Jenkins slave pod to do debugging?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

That slave-agent pod always seems to die and go away very quickly after an error in my Jenkinsfile. Is there a way to exec into it and keep it alive while I'm in it? I am running Jenkins on Kubernetes using Helm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the pod is already dead you can't `kubectl exec` into the container.

However, you can ssh directly into the node that ran your pod and inspect the (now stopped) container directly. (You can't `docker exec` into it once it stopped)

Something like this:

```
# this pod will die pretty quickly
$ kubectl run --restart=Never --image=busybox deadpod -- sh -c "echo quick death | tee /artifact"
pod "deadpod" created

$ kubectl describe pod deadpod
Name:           deadpod
Namespace:      default
Node:           nodexxx/10.240.0.yyy
Containers:
  deadpod:
   Container ID: docker://zzzzzzzzz
[...]

$ ssh nodexxx
```

**Once you have ssh'd into the node** you have several debugging options.

Get the output:

```
nodexxx:~# docker logs zzzz
quick death
```

Examine the filesystem:

```
nodexxx:~# mkdir debug; cd debug
nodexxx:~/debug# docker export zzz | tar xv
[...]
nodexxx:~/debug# ls -l; cat artifact
[...]
quick death
```

Create an image from the container, create a new container and get a shell:

```
nodexxx:~# docker commit zzzz debug
nodexxx:~# docker run -it zzzz sh
/ # cat /artifact
quick death
```

Comment: Thank you. Your example worked with busybox, but when I did the same for Jenkins, it said "Error: No such container zzzz" :(

Comment: Are you sure it's the right node? Also, eventually the containers are garbage collected

Comment: Turns out my issue not specifying enough RAM and CPU for the Jenkins slaves, so the pods would die almost instantly when it got to a certain location that required more resources